# Set button clickable property to false

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I need to disable the `click-event` for a button in Android. Just as a sample, I have tried doing the following. I have taken a `TextView` named it (entered a text) as *Name*. The condition checks if, `TextView` is empty button and clickable should be set to false. However this does not happen when the Toast is printed. Can somemone tell me the reason. Also if the text field is not empty I want to reset  the `clickable event` for button as true.

**Java File:**

```
public class ButtonclickabkeActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText("Name");
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        if (tv.getText().toString().length() != 0) {
            btn.setClickable(false);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + tv.getText().toString().length(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            btn.setClickable(true);
        }
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"/>
    <TextView 
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use

```
btn.setEnable(false);
```

instead of

```
btn.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: Thank  i set   btRegsiter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: `setClickable(false)` on LinearLayout without child view not working. `onClickListener` always fire when clicked. Even in XML `clickable:false` not working. Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

User 370305 is correct. `.setEnable` is what your looking for. Or you could use `android:clickable` in the layout XML file.

Comment: android:clickable is only used to determine if the view handles touch events or not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         view.setEnabled(false);
    }
 });
```